# conjugate algebraic numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Describe the set of algebraic numbers which conjugate a number $\root 5 \of 6$+$\root 3 \of 7$ and find a power his minimal polynomial.I know that need find automorphism which translates this number to another, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You do know the answer if we ask the same question about $\root5\of6$ or $\root3\of7$, don't you? Does that suggest something?

Comment: Assuming that you know already that it has $5 \cdot 3 = 15$ conjugates ( including itself), can you find them?

Comment: $\root 5 \of 6 \mapsto -\root 5\of 6$
$\root 5 \of 6 \mapsto w\root 5\of 6$
$\root 5 \of 6 \mapsto w^2\root 5\of 6$
$\root 5 \of 6 \mapsto w^3\root 5\of 6$
$\root 5 \of 6 \mapsto w^4\root 5\of 6$
similary for $\root 3 \of7$
and a minimal polynomial is multiplication result of all possible combinations of their sums or differences

Answer (score 1):

Like you noted, a polynomial with iteger coefficients that has it as a root is 
$$\prod_{\omega_1^5 = 1, \omega_2^3 = 1}(X - ( \omega_1 \sqrt[5]{6} +\omega_2 \sqrt[3]{7} ))$$

If you knew that this polynomial is irreducible, you would have the maximal number of conjugates ( $15$). Some reasoning is required to show that the degree of the number is in fact $15$.

Comment: Why not $\prod_{\omega_1^5 = 1, \omega_2^3 = 1}(X +- ( \omega_1 \sqrt[5]{6} +- \omega_2 \sqrt[3]{7} ))$ ?

Comment: @Aqwer:  Aha, I corrected the mistake, it should have been a $+$ inside the bracket. Thanks!

Comment: Why inside the bracket not a $\pm$?

Comment: @Aqwer: You don't need a $\pm$, you only take the conjugates of each term. And $-\sqrt[5]{6}$ is not a conjugate of $\sqrt[5]{6}$.

Comment: oh, I confused, it's not a minimal polynomial, then a minimal polynomial will has the form $\prod_{\omega_1^5 = 1, \omega_2^3 = 1}(X \pm( \omega_1 \sqrt[5]{6} \pm \omega_2 \sqrt[3]{7} ))$?

Comment: that I am confused again, a minimal polynomial will be the same, right?

Comment: @Aqwer the one that i wrote is the minimal pol over Q

Comment: Yes, clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT.-$\root 5\of 6+\root 3 \of 7$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb Q(\root 5\of 6,\root 3 \of 7)=\mathbb Q(\root 5\of 6)|\mathbb Q(\root 3 \of 7)$ whose degree is clearly $15$.

The minimal polynomial of $x=\root 5\of 6+\root 3 \of 7$ is
$$f(x)=x^{15}-35x^{12}-18x^{10}+490x^9-3780x^7-3430x^6+108x^5-39690x^4+12005x^3-7560x^2-30870x-17023$$ and all the fifteen roots should be distinct. A way of described implicitly the set of these could be using the relations of Vieta about the coefficients ($x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{15}=35$, etc). I can not see an explicit way to do it.

(*By the way the polynomial above has been obtained with Wolfram because getting it by hand would be quite hard*).